# Getting error 502 when using REST API to retrieves list of all applications

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

```
GET /imfpush/v1/apps HTTP/1.1
Host: mobilefoundation-3b-mf-server.mybluemix.net
Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImp....
Content-Type: application/json
```

another type of invocation

```
curl -X GET -H "Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1N...." "https://mobilefoundation-3b-mf-server.mybluemix.net/imfpush/v1/apps"
```

Error 502: Failed to make token request, reason: Unsuccessful request to Authorization Server, server responded with status code: 400 and body : {"errorCode":"invalid_client"}, check the Authorization URL: http://localhost:8080/mfp/api/az/v1/token

Comment: That does not look like the correct REST API to obtain a list of applications from the server. Additionally it does not look like you obtained an access token to gain access to the server...

Comment: When i check log in kibana i found this error : [ERROR ] Unable to obtain access token, if working in external-AZ mode, verify you have set clientId/clientSecret to null

Comment: See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: right now looks like there is a bug in the `/imfpush/v1/apps` endpoint where it does not filter the applications by the vendor (APNS, GCM, WNS), so you can only get a list of all applications instead...

---

Note however that it all depends on your end goal. You can accomplish this by code or by using tools such as curl or Postman, Swagger etc... it all depends on what you want to achieve.

Here are 3 ways:

1. In the **local development server** - not available in Mobile Foundation service on Bluemix, you can [use this URL](http://localhost:9080/doc/?url=/imfpush/v1/swagger.json) to see the REST endpoints exposed in Swagger. You can then view push-enabled applications with this one: http://localhost:9080/doc/?url=/imfpush/v1/swagger.json#!/Applications/getAllApplications

   - First, in **MobileFirst Operations Console > Runtime Settings > Confidential clients**:
   - Add (just an example, choose your own) a new `user` client (id: `user`, secret: `user`)
   - Add the `apps.read` and `push.application.*` scopes

   Be sure to click on the knob and add the `apps.read` and `push.applications.*` scopes.

   You will also be asked to authorize. Use the username and password for the `user` confidential client that you previously created.

[image]

2. Using the /imfpush service, as described below.
3. Using the mfpadmin service, as described below.

In my examples I will use Postman.

---

1. In **MobileFirst Operations Console > Runtime Settings > Confidential clients**:

   - Added (just an example, choose your own) a new `user` client (id: `user`, secret: `user`)
   - Added the `apps.read` and `push.application.*` scopes
2. Obtained an access token by making a POST request to `http://localhost:9080/mfp/api/az/v1/token` with:

   Authorization tab:

   - Type: Basic Auth
   - user: user
   - password: user

   Body tab:

   - x-www—form-urlencoded
   - grant_code: client_credentials
   - scope: apps.read push.application.*
3. Obtained the list of applications by making a GET request to `http://localhost:9080/imfpush/v1/apps` with:

   Headers tab:

   - Authorization: `Bearer the-access-token-from-step-2`
4. To filter the list by platform, the URL should change to the following, like the example in the [API documentation](http://engtest01w.francelab.fr.ibm.com:9090/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_8.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/rest_runtime/r_restapi_push_applications_get.html?cp=SSNJXP): `http://localhost:9080/imfpush/v1/apps/?expand=true&filter=platform==A&offset=0&size=10` But since this does not work right now... use: `http://localhost:9080/imfpush/v1/apps/`

Of course, you need to change `localhost` to your server's host.

[image]

---

To only obtain a list of all applications, it'd be faster to use the `mfpadmin` service `applications` endpoint. Using Postman:

1. Created a new GET request to `http://localhost:9080/mfpadmin/management-apis/2.0/runtimes/mfp/applications`

   You can change the domain to yours.
2. In the **Authorization** tab, I have set the following:

   - Type: Basic Auth
   - Username and Password: your username and password (to the console)

In return I have received a list of registered applications.

[image]